# Python basic round use

Tags: python, rounding

So I started learning to program last week, and now I can't figure it out by myself. I need final answer to be "Size between 24 to 192." But if I round it, it gives me 192.0. What do I need to change?

```
minp = 23.75
maxp = 192.4
minp1 = round(minp, 0)
maxp1 = round(maxp, 0)
print("Size between " + str(minp1) + " to " + str(maxp1) + ".")
```

Comment: Just drop the `, 0` part: `round(minp)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the type of `minp1` and `maxp1` are still **`float`s**, you can change them to **`int`s** by passing them to the `int(..)` constructor:

```
minp = 23.75
maxp = 192.4
minp1 = int(round(minp, 0))
maxp1 = int(round(maxp, 0))
print("Size between " + str(minp1) + " to " + str(maxp1) + ".")
```

Or in a terminal:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> minp = 23.75
>>> maxp = 192.4
>>> minp1 = int(round(minp, 0))
>>> maxp1 = int(round(maxp, 0))
>>> print("Size between " + str(minp1) + " to " + str(maxp1) + ".")
Size between 24 to 192.
```

Nevertheless, it is not a good idea to do string processing/concatenations yourself. You better format it with a [*formatting string*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-bytes-formatting), like:

```
minp = 23.75
maxp = 192.4
minp1 = round(minp, 0)
maxp1 = round(maxp, 0)
print("Size between %d to %d."%(minp1,maxp1))
```

Here `%d` stands for "*Signed integer decimal*". So by using format, Python will fill in the variables at the `%d` places itself which is elegant and requires less thinking from your side.

Comment: @user7438048: excellent suggestion. Added that to the answer.

Comment: `int(round(minp, 0))` would be simpler as `round(minp)`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: yeah but it would not explain why the misprint is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to leave the numbers as `float` and specifically output in integer format:

```
def r(val):
    return "{0:.0f}".format(round(val))

minp = 23.75
maxp = 192.4
print("Size between {0} to {1}.".format(r(minp), r(maxp)))
```

**Result:**

```
Size between 24 to 192.
```